How to change dropdown menu color in andriod
So I am developing a andriod application, and I was adding a menu, but I can't change it's color. I have read a lot of other stackoverflow questions and answers on this, and tried everything I found, but nothing helped. Here's some of my xml files that should (to my knowledge) have some effect on this.
res/menu/main_menu.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_changelog"
        android:title="@string/changelog" />
</menu>

res/values/themes/themes.xml:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/night</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

        <style name="CustomPopupMenu" parent="Widget.Material3.PopupMenu">
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
            <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
            <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
        </style>

        <style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Base.Theme.AppName" />
    </resources>


    
    
        
        @color/night
        @style/CustomPopupMenu
    
    <style name="CustomPopupMenu" parent="Widget.Material3.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@color/dark_night</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Base.Theme.AppName" />
</resources>

This is how it looks:

As I said, I tried everything I could find, even using a new drawable, but nothing changed this.
I made sure I am using the right theme in AndroidManifest.xml
I tested this on an emulator and on a real device, and the result didn't change.
I tred clearing cache and restarting andriod studio, but that didn't help.

Try to chance the parent attribute of your CustomPopupMeny style to  "@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow"

@dect Thanks, but sadly that didn't help either
